# ArrayList to MessageBox C#

Tags: c#

I was just wondering how can I print an entire ArrayList in a MessageBox?
Here is what I currently have:

```
    ArrayList myData = new ArrayList();
    ...bunch of Strings added to myData...
    private void btnDisplayScores_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(myData); <-----what I need help with
    }
```

Comment: Just curious, do you _have_ to use `ArrayList`? Generally it is strongly recommended to use `List<T>` instead unless you truly have an list of `object` types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try converting an *obsolete* `ArrayList` to `IEnumerable<Object>` and then `Join` items together:

```
 MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, myData.OfType<Object>()));
```

A better design is to change `ArrayList` to `List<Object>` (or `List<String>` if `myData` should have just `String` items):

```
 List<Object> myData = new List<Object>();
 ...
 MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, myData));
```

Comment: also if the OP wants to have the strings separated by `,` then replace the `Environment.NewLine` with `string.Join(",", myData);` this is a good trick to use if you ever have to build comma delim outputs `Hint Hint`